# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ipy"

Tags: python, ipython, pydev, anaconda

Trying to configure pydev to use an iron python interpreter (from Anaconda) as the interpreter.

- First tried pydev's Auto-Config:

> Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->IronPythonInterpreter->Quick
>   Auto-Config

- Produces this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "ipy": CreateProcess error=2,

- There is no ipy.exe on my system. There is however, C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython.exe. This executable does open a python REPL.
- I tried creating a new configuration instance manually and set "Interpreter Executable" to C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython.exe. At first, that produces the error:

> See error log for details. Unable to recreate the Interpreter info
>   (Its format changed. Please, re-create your Interpreter
>   information).Contents found:  IPython

- I removed -X from "Vm arguments for internal shell" under Preferences->...->IronPython Interpreters, but the error remains.
- The new configuration for the interpreter was added.
- However, it points the C:\Anaconda\python.exe and NOT C:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython.exe
- I created an IronPython Run configuration based on the interpreter and run it, this message print to the console:

> -X is reserved for implementation-specific arguments usage: C:\Anaconda\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg]
>   ... Try `python -h' for more information.

- ipython.exe does not support -X
- python.exe supports -x, but not -X

According the run configuration, this is the command line and PYTHONPATH:

> C:\Anaconda\python.exe -u -X:FullFrames
>   C:\py-eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd.py
>   --multiprocess --vm_type python --client 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --file C:\Users\Live\WebstormProjects\uni-poc\python\ThinkStats\thinkstats\survey.py
>
> The PYTHONPATH that will be used is:
>   C:\py-eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize;C:\Users\Live\WebstormProjects\uni-poc\python\ThinkStats;.;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\DLLs;C:\Anaconda\lib;C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\runipy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-3.6-py2.7.egg;C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions;C:\Users\Live.ipython

- Pydev is still sending -X to C:\Anaconda\python.exe and that is not going to work.

  - Configuration:
  - Windows 8.1, 64-bit
  - Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2
  - pydev_3.05.0.20.1405201...
  - Anaconda 2.1 for Windows 64-bit

Comment: *Face palm*. Note to self: never install software while sleep deprived and hallucinating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ipython](http://ipython.org) is not [IronPython](http://ironpython.net). ipython is an enhanced Python shell; IronPython is Python for the CLR (.NET/Mono). If you want IronPython you'll need to [download it separately](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/90087).